# New Pull Request menu item greyed out/disabled in Visual Studio 2022 17.9.0 Preview 2.1

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, pull-request

I have a pretty recent version of Visual Studio 2022 (17.9.0 preview 2.1) and am trying to create a PR from within the IDE.  I am on a feature branch and have tried committing some items (to Azure DevOps), which get pushed successfully.

However, the New Pull Request and View Pull Requests menu item (under Git/Azure DevOps) is greyed out and I can't see to get it enabled.  I have enabled the PR preview feature from within the Visual Studio settings.

Why won't the new PR feature enable itself so that I can raise PRs from within the IDE?  I am able to raise PRs via the browser as normal.

I am talking about this feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-create-pull-request?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft added a note, detailing how you have to enable the feature before use:

`Tools > Options > Preview Features > Pull Request`

[image: Microsoft added a note, detailing how you have to enable the feature before use]

Comment: I had already done this but the feature still isn't active